# Conducting a t-test across two different data frames with switched rows/columns?

Tags: r, subset, t-test

Sorry for the confusing title, this one's a bit hard to describe. Basically, I've got two data tables which look similar to this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(SNP=c("W", "X", "Y", "Z"),
                  Gene.ID=c("A", "B", "C", "B"), pval=NA)
df2 <- data.frame(W=c(1, 0, 1), X=c(1, 1, 0), Y=c(0, 0, 1), Z=c(1, 0, 1),
                  A=c(3.5, 2.5, 3.5), C=c(4.5, 2.5, 1.5), B=c(1.5, 2.5, 1.5))
```

So all the entries in df1 correspond to column names in df2. My goal is to fill df1$pval with the p-values from a t-test. For every row in df1, I want to do a t-test comparing the df2 column that matches the value of df1$SNP, and compares that against the df2 column that matches the value of df1$Gene.ID.

For example, for the first row in df1, I would want to compare df2$W vs. df2$A, and then return the resulting p-value inside of df1[1, 3]. For the second row, I would compare df2$X vs. df2$B and return the p-value in df1[2, 3]. In other words, something like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  test <- t.test(df2[,which(colnames(df2)==df1[i, 1]] ~ df2[,which(colnames(df2)==df1[i, 2]])
  df1[i, 3] <- test$p.value
}
```

But this does not work because you can only select multiple column names using the `colnames` function, not just a single column name. Suggestions for how to get around this would be greatly appreciated--or if you have a simpler method in mind, that would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `which(colnames(df2)...)` may not be the best choice here, since all you want to do is to select the columns of `df2` that have `df1[i,1]` or `df1[i,2]` as names.

In R, one way to select a column by its name is to use the double brackets: e.g. `df2[["A"]]` will retrieve the column `A` of `df2`, which seems to be what you want, and less cumbersome than `df2[, which(colnames(df2) == "A")]`.

With that in mind, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  test <- t.test(df2[[df1[i, 2]]] ~ df2[[df1[i, 1]]])
  df1[i, 3] <- test$p.value
}
```

Notice that I switched `df1[i, 1]` and `df1[i, 2]` since the documentation of `t.test` states that the binary variable has to be on the right hand side.

> a formula of the form lhs ~ rhs where lhs is a numeric variable giving the data values and rhs a factor with two levels giving the corresponding groups

Comment: That double bracket trick is really handy! I didn't realize you could do this without the $ operator. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah, I was a big fan of the `$`, it's simpler to use, but `[[...]]` offers a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you think this wouldn't work - I think your code just has syntax errors in it. The following code seems to work fine (note the change to use `sapply`, which is slightly more conventional in R):

```
df1[, 3] <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 
  function(i) {
    test <- t.test(
      df2[, which(colnames(df2) == df1[i, 1])],
      df2[, which(colnames(df2) == df1[i, 2])])
    test$p.value
  })
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just doing something wrong, but I can't seem to get colnames to work with just a single column. For example, if I were to type `colnames(df[,1])` the output is NULL, where as `colnames(df[,1:2]` returns SNP and Gene.ID.

Comment: Look at the output of `df[, 1]` vs `df[, 1:2]` or `df[, 1, drop=FALSE]`, and see the following sections (8.1.44 and 45): http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#page=68

Comment: btw I don't mean to sound short - it is a common mistake, and you are in fact merely expecting logical and consistent behaviour from R - something I'm sure you'll stop doing with time :)